# MediaPlayer / VideoView not playing video?

Tags: java, android, video, media-player, android-videoview

I'm new to android development, self taught so can expect a few errors here and there but none so irritating as this. I've looked over my code a thousand times, searched high and low across multiple websites, books and forums for an answer but I still get the same error so this is a last resort.

I just want to play a hardcoded path to a video in an activity, which is part of my video portfolio app. (The hardcoded path is just for testing, later I will call each video from the related button press, but only after I sort the player out!).

Here is my code:

```
String path = "android.resource://mysite/res/raw/video1"; 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_videoplayer);

    VideoView view = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.vv);
    MediaController controller = (MediaController) new MediaController(this);

    controller.setMediaPlayer(view);
    view.setVideoPath(path);
    view.requestFocus();
    view.start();
}
```

This snippet is inside my VideoPlayer class, where vv is the VideoView in the XML and video1 is the video to be played. The video is h.264 mp4, 1 minute long and 3mb in size and can be played normally through the default player.

XML:

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/vv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

The activity loads but returns the error "Can't play this video".

Any help I greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     VideoView view = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.vv);

        view.setVideoPath(path);
        view.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        view.requestFocus();
        view.start();
```

Use like this. hope this will give you some solution.

Comment: Thanks! A step in the right direction, the activity now loads the videoview but then crashes when loading the video file, instead of just returning an error without doing anything. I think I was overcomplicating things. I can learn from this and adjust the activity now. Why do you think it crashes on loading the file? Could the path be wrong or the codecs? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

According Android's [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) Video decoding support for MP4(h.264) added from android 3.0+, so I think you are playing this video on version below 3.0. Try it on the device which has android os version 3.0+.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tested it on CM9 on my HTC Desire (which I believe is based on ICS) and 4.1.2 JB on my GS3, so they should both work. I'm really stumped. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
video0=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vv);
video0.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
video0.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" +getPackageName()+ "/" +R.raw.video1));
video0.requestFocus();
video0.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    mc.setAnchorView(vv);

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).